# How can I change the label font to fit the control size?

Tags: c#, winforms

I created an ew User Control.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Extract
{
    public partial class TimeCounter : UserControl
    {
        private Timer _timer;
        private Label _label;
        private int _elapsedSeconds;

        public TimeCounter()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _timer = new Timer
            {
                Interval = 1000,
                Enabled = true
            };
            _timer.Tick += (sender, args) =>
            {
                _elapsedSeconds++;
                TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_elapsedSeconds);
                _label.Text = time.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
            };

            _label = new Label();

            _label.Font = new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold);

            Controls.Add(_label);
        }

        private void TimeCounter_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

This is when the font size of the label is 10 :
The font is too small to the control size.

[image: font too small]

If I change the font size to 24 then it's too big from the inside of the control.

[image: Too big font]

Is there a way to fit the label font by code to the control size ?

If I set the font size to 10 then resize the control size to fit it or change the font size to the control size same if I set the font size for example to 24 or 15 or any size.

The way it is now I have to change the font size each time drag the control to form1 see how it is delete it from form1 designer and change the font size and over again. this is too much work.

Comment: Derive your class from Label instead of UserControl.  So it behaves like a label, you'll get the AutoSize behavior for free.

Comment: Hans suggestion is working great. thanks.

Comment: @HansPassant How can I change the counter direction if to count up or down ? I tried to change this line to -- instead ++ _elapsedSeconds++; but it keep counting up.